# Como crear filtro por cada columna de una tabla con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Objetivo - Puede ser en jquery o vanilla javascript**

Pienso yo, crear filtros dependientes, es decir. Un filtro B solo podra buscar datos filtrados por filtro A. Un ejemplo seria, si en la columna A escribo c, la columna B solo podra buscar entre d o f. Si en tal caso se coloca b, no deberia pasar nada ya que este dato no esta dentro del filtro A

**Codigo Actual**

1. Cuando busco A en la columna uno, y luego coloco D en la columna dos, la tabla se desaparece obviamente
2. Estoy colocando empty, porque luego necesitaria exportar lo filtrado con excel (exportara lo que tenga la tabla en el dom)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#inputUno').keyup(function () {
            $("#table td.col1:contains('" + $(this).val() + "')").parent().show();
            $("#table td.col1:not(:contains('" + $(this).val() + "'))").parent().empty();
        });
        $('#inputDos').keyup(function () {
            $("#table td.col2:contains('" + $(this).val() + "')").parent().show();
            $("#table td.col2:not(:contains('" + $(this).val() + "'))").parent().empty();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="text" id="inputUno"><input type="text" id="inputDos"><br>
    <table id="table" border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td class="col1" width='100px'>a</td>
            <td class="col2" width='100px'>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="col1" width='100px'>c</td>
            <td class="col2" width='100px'>d</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="col1" width='100px'>c</td>
            <td class="col2" width='100px'>f</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: No entiendo entonces cual es el problema si ya lograste el objetivo

Comment: Parece que ya estás filtrando los datos ¿Puede que tu problema sea al quitar el filtro porque no vuelve a recuperar lo que había?

Comment: Buen dia. Si, esta filtrando pero si hacemos este ejercicio, coloquemos en la columna 1 la letra c, el filtro se haria, pero ahora para la columna 2 unicamente deberia buscar registros de lo que se filtro, es decir solo deberia filtrar entre d y f @JaviMollá

Comment: Buen dia. Si, esta filtrando pero si hacemos este ejercicio, coloquemos en la columna 1 la letra c, el filtro se haria, pero ahora para la columna 2 unicamente deberia buscar registros de lo que se filtro, es decir solo deberia filtrar entre d y f @AlbertoSiurob

Comment: ¿Quieres decir que lo que pones en inputUno también debería filtrar lo de la columna 2? No acabo de entender lo que pretendes hacer

Comment: hola @JaviMollá no, si colocas en la columna uno c, te hara el filtro sin problemas. Es decir tendras para filtrar en la col2 unicamente d o f,por ej no podrias buscar b ya esa opcion ya no esta visible

Comment: Pero entonces lo que quieres es que se muestren todas las filas que incluyan valores de una columna o de otra, ¿no? Que porque una columna no tenga el valor de uno de los dos inputs no desaparezca

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84090/discussion-between-alex-hunter-and-javi-molla).

Comment: hola @JaviMollá se habilito el chat, mejor hablemos por alla, te parece? ya te escribi

Answer (score 9):

Pienso, humildemente, que la lógica está mal planteada. Por las siguientes razones:

1. La eliminación de las filas que no cumplen debiera hacerse **al momento de exportar la tabla y no antes**. De lo contrario, si modificas los filtros, las filas que antes hubiesen cumplido ahora ya no existen.
2. Pensemos que implementaste lo anterior y las filas no se borran sino que se marcan para borrar al momento de exportar. Tu filtro debiera ser una condición **AND**, pero de la manera como lo tienes planteado, puede ocurrir el siguiente flujo:

   - Escribes `a` en el primer input. Las filas 2 y 3 se marcan para eliminar.
   - Escribes `d` en el segundo input. Ahora la fila 1 se marca para eliminar (porque su columna 2 no contiene `d`) pero las filas 2 y 3 se marcan como si cumplieran el filtro. Básicamente, acabas de ignorar el filtro 1 porque sólo comprobaste el cumplimiento con el filtro 2. Esto no lo puedes detectar con tu approach actual porque la fila se borra y pareciera que es un filtro `AND`, pero en realidad el último input que recibe un `keyup` condiciona a toda la tabla.
3. Al momento de exportar la tabla no basta con hacer que el elemento `td` quede vacío. Debieras removerlo completamente. A lo mejor te está funcionando bien la exportación, pero a mi modo de ver, un `td` da origen a una fila (en el excel) y cada celda da origen a una columna. Ergo, tu XLS puede tener filas en blanco. Debieras hacer un `remove()` en vez de un `empty()`.

Te dejo una implementación que pienso representa mejor lo que quieres hacer:

- Cada vez que escribes algo en cualquiera de los dos inputs, corre las dos comprobaciones. Marca con una clase `no_cumple` las celdas que no cumplen (letras en rojo) y una clase `cumple` (letras en verde) las que cumplan. De esta manera, puedes distinguir qué está haciendo el filtro exactamente.
- Por cada fila, aquellas que contengan al menos una celda con esa clase, se marcan con la clase `fila_eliminar` (borde rojo). Sólo aquellas que no contengan ninguna celda que incumpla los filtros se salvarán de la carnicería final.

Con este enfoque, al momento de exportar pones:

```
$('#table').find('.fila_eliminar').remove();
```

Dale una mirada a este snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#inputUno, #inputDos').keyup(function() {
    var cont1 = $('#inputUno').val().trim(),
      cont2 = $('#inputDos').val().trim(),
      tabla = $('#table');

    tabla.find('td.col1:contains(' + cont1 + ')')
      .removeClass('no_cumple')
      .addClass('cumple');

    tabla.find('td.col2:contains(' + cont2 + ')')
      .removeClass('no_cumple')
      .addClass('cumple');


    tabla.find('td.col1:not(:contains(' + cont1 + '))')
      .addClass('no_cumple')
      .removeClass('cumple');


    tabla.find('td.col2:not(:contains(' + cont2 + '))')
      .addClass('no_cumple')
      .removeClass('cumple');

    tabla.find('tr').removeClass('fila_eliminar').find('.col3').text('se queda');
    tabla.find('tr .no_cumple').each(function() {
      $(this).parent().addClass('fila_eliminar').find('.col3').text('se borra');
    });

  });

});
```

```css
.no_cumple {
  color: red;
}

.cumple {
  color: green;
}

.fila_eliminar {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.fila_eliminar .col3 {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table" border='1'>
  <thead>
    <th>
      <input type="text" id="inputUno" placeholder="texto a filtrar">
    </th>
    <th>
      <input type="text" id="inputDos" placeholder="texto a filtrar">
    </th>
    <th>
      Diagnóstico
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1" width='100px'>a</td>
      <td class="col2" width='100px'>b</td>
      <td class="col3" width='100px'>se queda</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1" width='100px'>c</td>
      <td class="col2" width='100px'>d</td>
      <td class="col3" width='100px'>se queda</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1" width='100px'>c</td>
      <td class="col2" width='100px'>f</td>
      <td class="col3" width='100px'>se queda</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

## Edit, objetivo reformulado:

Según tu objetivo reformulado, el filtro B sólo opera sobre las filas que sobrevivieron al filtro A. En la solución que te puse esto se logra implícitamente porque dada una combinación de A y B que descarta todas las filas, ninguna califica para la exportación.

Pero si tú quieres que el usuario primero filtre por A y luego por B, que si en B pones algo que simplemente no está entre las filas que sobrevivieron, no ocurra nada. En este caso el flujo podría ser:

- Utilizo dos elementos `<tbody>`. El primero contiene las filas que no cumplen y el segundo las que sí cumplen. Los filtros mueven las filas de un `<tbody>` al otro.
- El filtro B parte desactivado
- Pongo algo en el filtro A, y algunas filas califican
- Se desbloquea el filtro B
- Pongo algo en el filtro B y

  - Si algunas filas califican, se aplica el filtro B en conjunto con el A
  - Si ninguna califica, el filtro B no tiene efecto
  - Si vacías el filtro B, se vuelve a aplicar el filtro A solamente
  - Si vacías el filtro A, todo vuelve al comienzo
- Al momento de exportar, elimino el `<tbody>` de las que no cumplen.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('#inputUno').keyup(function() {
    var cont1 = $('#inputUno').val().trim(),
      tabla = $('#table');


    tabla.find('td.col1:contains(' + cont1 + ')')
      .parent()
      .appendTo('#filas_cumplen');

    tabla.find('td.col1:not(:contains(' + cont1 + '))')
      .parent()
      .appendTo('#filas_no_cumplen');

    tabla.find('#filas_cumplen').find('.col3').text('se queda');
    tabla.find('#filas_no_cumplen').find('.col3').text('se borra');
    $('#inputDos').removeAttr('disabled').attr('placeholder', 'texto a filtrar').val('');

    if (cont1 === '') {
      $('#inputDos').val('').attr('disabled', true).attr('placeholder', 'debe llenar primer filtro')

    }
  });

  $('#inputDos').on('keyup', function() {
    var cont2 = $('#inputDos').val().trim(),
      tbody = $('#filas_cumplen'),
      tabla = $('#table');

    if (cont2 === '') {
      $('#inputUno').keyup();
      return;
    }
    var cumplen = tbody.find('td.col2:contains(' + cont2 + ')');
    if (cumplen.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    tbody.find('td.col2:not(:contains(' + cont2 + '))')
      .parent()
      .appendTo('#filas_no_cumplen');

    tabla.find('#filas_cumplen').find('.col3').text('se queda');
    tabla.find('#filas_no_cumplen').find('.col3').text('se borra');

  });

});
```

```css
#filas_cumplen {
  color: green;
}

#filas_no_cumplen {
  color: red;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#filas_no_cumplen .col3 {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table" border='1'>
  <thead>
    <th>
      <input type="text" id="inputUno" placeholder="texto a filtrar">
    </th>
    <th>
      <input type="text" id="inputDos" placeholder="debe llenar primer filtro" disabled="true">
    </th>
    <th>
      Diagnóstico
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="filas_no_cumplen">
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="filas_cumplen">
    <tr>
      <td class="col1" width='100px'>a</td>
      <td class="col2" width='100px'>b</td>
      <td class="col3" width='100px'>se queda</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1" width='100px'>c</td>
      <td class="col2" width='100px'>d</td>
      <td class="col3" width='100px'>se queda</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1" width='100px'>c</td>
      <td class="col2" width='100px'>f</td>
      <td class="col3" width='100px'>se queda</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: hola, pido disculpas porque tienes razon, acabo de reformular mi objetivo

Answer (score 3):

Te presento una alternativa utilizando Javascript Vanilla.

Se hace uso de setAttribute y getAttribute, así como de querySelectorAll.
Se explican la funcionalidad con comentarios en el código

```js
window.onload = function () {
 //Se le da el attributo hiddenbyfilter a todas las filas de la tabla
 let rows = document.querySelectorAll("#table tr");
 for (let i=0; i < rows.length; i++) rows[i].setAttribute("hiddenByFilter", 0);
 
 //Se asigna la funcion de filtrado al evento keyup 
 let input_1 = document.querySelector("#inputUno");
 input_1.addEventListener("keyup", filter);
 
 let input_2 = document.querySelector("#inputDos");
 input_2.addEventListener("keyup", filter);

}

function filter () {
  //this -> corresponde al input en el cual se da el evento keyup
  //Valor del input
  let searchValue = this.value;
  //Listado de las filas de la tabla (tr)
  let rows = document.querySelectorAll("#table tr");
  //Indicador de que columna debe filtrar el input
  let filterForColumn = this.getAttribute("filterForColumn");

  for (let i=0; i < rows.length; i++){
   //Si la fila no tiene filtro o si el nuevo filtro tiene precedencia
   if (rows[i].getAttribute("hiddenByFilter") == 0 ||
     filterForColumn <= rows[i].getAttribute("hiddenByFilter")
   ){
    //Se aplica filtro a la fila
    rows[i].setAttribute("hiddenByFilter", filterForColumn);
    //Se obtiene la celda (td)
    let cell = rows[i].querySelector("td:nth-child("+filterForColumn+")");
    //Si el texto de la celda es igual al buscado o si el valor buscado es vacio
    if (cell.innerText == searchValue || searchValue === "") {
     //Se quita el filtro de la fila
     rows[i].setAttribute("hiddenByFilter", 0);
    }
   }
  }  
}
```

```css
/*Muestra solo los que tengan el atributo hiddenbyfilter en 0*/
tr:not([hiddenByFilter="0"]) {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputUno" filterForColumn="1"><input type="text" id="inputDos" filterForColumn="2"><br>
<table id="table" border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td class="col1" width='100px'>a</td>
    <td class="col2" width='100px'>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col1" width='100px'>c</td>
    <td class="col2" width='100px'>d</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col1" width='100px'>c</td>
    <td class="col2" width='100px'>f</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Como comentas requerir quitar del DOM los resultados que no coinciden con la búsqueda podrías alterar la función filter por algo similar a:

```
function filter () {
    let searchValue = this.value;
    let rows = document.querySelectorAll("#table tr");
    let filterForColumn = this.getAttribute("filterForColumn");

    for (let i=0; i < rows.length; i++){
        if (rows[i].getAttribute("hiddenByFilter") == 0){
            let cell = rows[i].querySelector("td:nth-child("+filterForColumn+")");
            if ( cell.innerText != searchValue ) {
                rows[i].remove();
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo hagas uso de la librería [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) la cual te permite hacer un ordenamiento por columna, paginación, es responsiva y te provee la exportación a Csv, pdf, excel etc..

El ejemplo que he agregado te permite el filrtro por columna o de manera general

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Buscar'+title+'" />' );
    } );
 
 
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
"language": {
        search: 'Buscar:',
        "lengthMenu": "Mostrando _MENU_ registros por pagina",
        "zeroRecords": "Sin datos",
        "info": "Mostrando _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
        "infoEmpty": "Sin registros",
        "infoFiltered": "(filtrados de _MAX_)",
paginate: {
    first: 'Primero',
    previous: 'Anterior',
    next: 'Siguiente',
    last: 'Último',
  }
    }
});
    table.columns().every( function () {
        var that = this;
 
        $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );
} );
```

```css
tfoot input {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 3px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009/06/25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011/12/12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010/09/20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010/12/22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010/11/14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2011/06/07</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>2010/03/11</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>2011/08/14</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2011/06/02</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>2009/10/22</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/05/07</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2008/10/26</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/03/09</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/12/09</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/12/16</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2010/02/12</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>2009/02/14</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2008/12/11</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>2008/09/26</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2011/02/03</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>2011/05/03</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2009/08/19</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2013/08/11</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/07/07</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2012/04/09</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2010/01/04</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>2012/06/01</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2013/02/01</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/12/06</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2011/03/21</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2009/02/27</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2010/07/14</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shad Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/11/13</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011/06/27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: hola, muchas gracias. Pero quiero hacerla sin plugins

Answer (score 0):

como puedo filtar cuando es Multiselect

```
$('#selectmulti_ug').on('keyup change', function () { //'input', this.footer()
        if (table.column(9).search() !== this.value) {
            table.column(9)
                   .search(this.value)
                    .draw();
        }
```

**HTML**

```
   <div id="idFiltrosRGT" class="form-group col-sm-10">
                                <table id="idTablaFiltrosRGT">
                                    <thead>
                                    <th style="text-align: center; width: 12%;">Zona</th>
                                    <th style="text-align: center; width: 15%;">Tienda</th>
                                    <th style="text-align: center; width: 20%;">Estado</th>
                                    <th style="text-align: center; width: 10%;">Ultima Gestion</th>
                                    <th style="text-align: center; width: 10%;">Asesor</th>
                                    <th style="text-align: center; width: 10%;"></th>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="tblBodyFiltrosRGT">
                                    <th style="text-align: center; width: 10%;"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="txtZona" placeholder="Zona" style="font-size:10px;"/></th>
                                    <th style="text-align: center; width: 10%;"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="txtTienda" placeholder="Tienda" style="font-size:10px;"/></th>
                                    <th style="text-align: center; width: 15%;">
                                    <select id="selectmulti" multiple="multiple" >
                                    <option value="NUEVO" >NUEVO</option>
                                    <option value="PENDIENTE" >PENDIENTE</option>
                                    <option value="EN EVALUACION" >EN EVALUACION</option>
                                    <option value="DESEMBOLSADO" >DESEMBOLSADO</option>
                                    <option value="FINALIZADO" >FINALIZADO</option>
                                    <option value="VENCIDO" >VENCIDO</option>
                                    <option value="WORFLOWS" >WORFLOWS</option>
                                    </select>
                                    </th> 
                                    <th style="text-align: center; width: 10%;">

                                    <select id="selectmulti_ug" multiple="multiple" >
                                    <option value="No tiene interes ahora" >No tiene interes ahora</option>
                                    <option value="Con Interes, Proxima visita" >Con Interes, Proxima visita</option>
                                    <option value="No califica por referencias" >No califica por referencias</option>
                                    <option value="No califica por Capacidad" >No califica por Capacidad</option>
                                    <option value="Direccion no existe" >Direccion no existe</option>
                                    <option value="Direccion existe y no lo conocen" >Direccion existe y no lo conocen</option>
                                    <option value="Direccion existe y esta mudado" >Direccion existe y esta mudado</option>
                                    <option value="Con interes, fecha a Desembolsar" >Con interes, fecha a Desembolsar</option>
                                    <option value="No se encuentra, proxima visita" >No se encuentra, proxima visita</option>
                                    <option value="Con Interes, Agenda visita a Asesor" >Con Interes, Agenda visita a Asesor</option>
                                    <option value="No contesta Teléfono" >No contesta Teléfono</option>
                                    <option value="Teléfono Apagado o inhabilitado" >Teléfono Apagado o inhabilitado</option>
                                    <option value="Teléfono no existe" >Teléfono no existe</option>
                                    </select>    
                                    </th>
                                    <th style="text-align: center; width: 10%;"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="txtAsesor" placeholder="Asesor" style="font-size:10px;"/></th>
                                    <th style="text-align: center; width: 10%;">
                                        <button id="btnLimpiarHSRGT" 
                                                class="btn btn-md btn-block" 
                                                onclick="fncLimpiarRGHS()" 
                                                type="submit"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></span> Limpiar
                                        </button>
                                    </th>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
```

Gracias..!!